# Querying sqlite db with Go but none of the rows are being scanned into variables

Tags: go, sqlite

I am running a query through Go using

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlstring)
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close()
```

this is the sql string with ? being '安'

```
select
  k_ele.value as kanji,  id as k_ele_id,
  NULL as r_ele_id, NULL as r_ele_val,
  NULL as gloss_id, NULL as gloss_val
from k_ele where value like ?
UNION ALL
select
  k_ele.value as kanji,  NULL as k_ele_id,
  r_ele.id as r_ele_id, r_ele.value as r_ele_val,
  NULL as gloss_id, NULL as gloss_val
from
  r_ele, k_ele where k_ele.value like ? and k_ele.fk = r_ele.fk
UNION ALL
select
  k_ele.value as kanji,  NULL as k_ele_id,
  NULL as r_ele_id, NULL as r_ele_val,
  gloss.id as gloss_id, gloss.value as gloss_val
from
  sense, gloss, k_ele
where
  k_ele.value like ? and
  k_ele.fk = sense.fk and
  gloss.fk = sense.id;
```

This query can be used fine through sqlite3 on console and DB Browser for SQLite and returns 8 rows and even the for loop in the go code loops 8 times.

The problem is that during

```
rows.Scan()
```

none of the column values are being stored in the variables except kanji which appears in every row (since it is in every row) but nothing but kanji is printed out in log.Println().

```
    rows, err := stmt.Query(parameter,parameter,parameter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var kanji, r_ele_val, gloss_val string
        var k_ele_id, r_ele_id, gloss_id int

        rows.Scan(&kanji,&k_ele_id,&r_ele_id,&r_ele_val,&gloss_id,&gloss_val)
        log.Println(kanji,k_ele_id, r_ele_id,r_ele_val,gloss_id,gloss_val)
    }
```

Here is the output (It is ? because my cmd can't print the japanese characters (if the ? is sent to my browser, it will properly show the character)

```
2015/02/11 22:18:42 ? 105921 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:42 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:18:43 ? 0 0  0
```

The strange thing is if I change the order of the columns for example putting gloss_id, gloss_val first in the select statement. **Every variable** gets 0 stored, even kanji before a gloss_id has a value. (These are the same sets of data)

```
2015/02/11 22:23:12  0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:23:12  0 0  0
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197326 cheap
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197327 rash
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197328 thoughtless
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197329 careless
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197330 indiscreet
2015/02/11 22:23:13 ? 0 0  197331 frivolous
```

The sql works perfectly fine in sqlite3, the Golang for loop runs the correct number of times as well. Here is what the data should look like.

[image: Query from DB Browser for SQLite]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or is there something wrong with what I'm doing? I suspect it is a problem with UNION ALL but I'm not sure how to get this working.

**EDIT:** I made rows.Scan return err this time as well as printout the columns

```
        err := rows.Scan(&kanji,&k_ele_id,&r_ele_id,&r_ele_val,&gloss_id,&gloss_val)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("rows.Column(): ")
            log.Println(rows.Columns())
            log.Println(kanji,k_ele_id, r_ele_id,r_ele_val,gloss_id,gloss_val)
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

2015/02/12 22:38:56 rows.Column():
2015/02/12 22:38:56 [kanji k_ele_id r_ele_id r_ele_val gloss_id gloss_val] <nil>

2015/02/12 22:38:56 ? 105921 0  0
2015/02/12 22:38:56 sql: Scan error on column index 2: converting string "<nil>"
 to a int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "<nil>": invalid syntax
```

The error message says that there is an attempt to convert string  to int in column index 2 (r_ele_id) but isn't r_ele_id an int already (as can be seen in the picture of my schema)? Because of the need to use UNION ALL for this query there are going to be NULLs in every row, I believe I need to use type NullInt64 instead of int for the *id types. Will try this now and report back

Comment: Dear lord - perhaps you could give us a smaller - nicer variable name - reproduction of your issue?

Comment: `rows.Scan` returns an error. Please inspect it, it may give you some pointers to the solution.

Comment: @Ainar-G I used Rows.Err() at the end of each loop iteration and that returned nil for each row but I will look at if rows.Scan returns an error when I get the chance later today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows.Scan will not scan value  to types int and string without throwing an error. The correct type to use was sql.NullInt64 and sql.NullString, these types will hold the value properly and have a bool val that is used to check whether it is nil or not.